# How to convert a recordset into a table in C#

Tags: c#, stored-procedures, recordset

I have a stored procedure which returns a recordset. How can I show that recordset data in a table on a site on C#? A hint or a tutorial link would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many, many ways to do this, depending on your technology.  Assuming you're using Visual Studio, the quickest (quick and dirty) might be to drag an ObjectDataSource or SqlDataSource onto the design surface and bind a component directly to it.

Here's a sample link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479341.aspx